# Empirical estimator for total variation distance between two product distributions

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-theory, probability-distributions, approximation-theory

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n)$ be an $n$-dimensional random variable, where each $X_i$ is a random variable on finite discrete set $S$. In addition, $X_i$ are independent of each other (but not identically distributed). That is, if we denote $X \sim \mathcal{D}$ and $X_i \sim \mathcal{D}_i$, then $\mathcal{D}$ is just the product of $\{ \mathcal{D}_i \}$.

Similarly, let $Y = (Y_1, Y_2, \ldots , Y_n) \sim \mathcal{D}'$ and $Y_i \sim \mathcal{D}'_i$ independently on $S$ (the same $S$ as $X_i$'s). Then $\mathcal{D}'$ is the product of $\{ \mathcal{D}'_i \}$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Now I don't know $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{D}'$ precisely but I can sample from them (so that I can sample from all the marginal distributions $\mathcal{D}_i$ and $\mathcal{D}'_i$ as well). I would like to estimate the total variation between $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{D}'$.

Let $d = \|\mathcal{D} - \mathcal{D}'\|_{TV}$ and $\hat{d}$ be our estimator for $d$. Let $N$ be the number of samples we need. I hope to get an error-confidence bound of the form
$$\Pr[ |\hat{d} - d| \ge \epsilon] \le \delta$$
where $\delta$ is at least polynomially small w.r.t. $n, |S|, N$ and $\epsilon$.

---

I just found [a similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140643/empirical-estimator-fot-the-total-variation-distance-on-a-finite-space). However, the sample space of $X$ and $Y$ here is $S^n$, which is exponentially large, making the bound in that post not applicable to this question. Besides, here we have $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{D}'$ being product distributions, which could probably make things easier.

Thank you.

Comment: The paper [Testing that distributions are close](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=892113&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D892113) is probably of interest to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something that may or may not be useful...

Diaconis notes  an interpretation of variation distance of Paul Switzer. Consider $\mu$, $\nu\in M_p(S)$. Given a single observation of $S$, sampled from $\mu$ or $\nu$ with probability $1/2$, guess whether the observation, $o$, was sampled from $\mu$ or $\nu$. The classical strategy presented here gives the probability of being correct as $1/2(1+\|\mu-\nu\|)$:

1. Evaluate $\mu(o)$ and $\nu(o)$.
2. If $\mu(o)\geq\nu(o)$, choose $\mu$.
3. If $\nu(o)>\mu(o)$, choose $\nu$.

To see this is true, let $\{\mu>\nu\}$  be the set $\{t\in S:\mu(t)>\nu(t)\}$.
Suppose $o$ is sampled from $\mu$. Then the strategy is correct if $o\in\{\mu=\nu\}$ or $o\in\{\mu>\nu\}$:
$$\mathbb{P}[\text{guessing correctly}\,|\,\mu]=\mathbb{P}[o\in\{\mu=\nu\}\,|\,\mu]+\mathbb{P}[o\in\{\mu>\nu\}\,|\,\mu]$$
with a similar expression for $\mathbb{P}[\text{guessing correctly}\,|\,\nu]$.

Note that $\mathbb{P}[o\in\{\mu=\nu\}]=\mu(\{\mu=\nu\})=\nu(\{\mu=\nu\})$ and also $\mathbb{P}[o\in\{\mu>\nu\}\,|\,\mu]=\mu(\{\mu>\nu\})$ (and similar for $o\in\{\mu<\nu\}$). Thus
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[\text{guessing correctly}] &=\frac12\mathbb{P}[\text{guessing correctly}\,|\,\mu]+\frac12\mathbb{P}[\text{guessing correctly}\,|\,\nu]
\\&=\frac12\left(\nu(\{\mu=\nu\})+\mu(\{\mu>\nu\})\right)+\frac12\left(\nu(\{\mu<\nu\})\right)
\end{align*}
It is easily shown that
$$\|\mu-\nu\|=\mu\left(\{\mu>\nu\}\right)-\nu\left(\{\mu>\nu\}\right).$$
Hence
$$
\mathbb{P}[\text{guessing correctly}]=\frac12\left(\underbrace{\nu(\{\mu=\nu\})+\nu(\{\mu>\nu\})+\nu(\{\mu<\nu\})}_{=1}+\|\mu-\nu\|)\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Anton, I think your "max" should be a "min".

If I understood your identity correctly, it means that if I define $\mu_n$ to be the product of $(p,1-p)$ Bernoulli measures on $\{0,1\}^n$ and $\nu_n$ to be the product of $(p',1-p')$ Bernoulli measures on $\{0,1\}^n$, then you're saying that
$$ ||\mu_n-\nu_n|| = |p-p'|^n $$
which decays to zero, while of course $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} ||\mu_n-\nu_n|| = 1$$
for $p\neq p'$.

A correct upper bound on the total variation between product distributions may be found in
https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.0987
(Lemma 2.2 for 2 distributions, which generalizes to $n$-fold products via the "inclusion-exclusion" formula in Lemma 4.2)

To answer the original question: that "inclusion-exclusion" bound I cited above implies that
$$ ||{\cal D} - {\cal D}'|| \le \sum_{i=1}^n ||{\cal D}_i - {\cal D}'_i||.$$

Further, by the triangle inequality, 
$$ ||\hat {\cal D}_i - \hat  {\cal D}'_i|| \le
||{\cal D}_i - \hat  {\cal D}_i||
+
||{\cal D}'_i - \hat  {\cal D}'_i||,
$$
where $\hat{\cdot}$  indicates the empirical distribution.
Finally, it is trivial to show that if we define
$$ J_i := ||{\cal D}_i - \hat  {\cal D}_i||, $$
then $\mathbb{E}[J_i] \le \sqrt{|S|/N}$
and
$$ \mathbb{P}( J_i > \mathbb{E}[J_i] + \epsilon) \le \exp(-N\epsilon^2/2) $$
[see (5) and (17) in
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715213000242
]. I believe this answers your question.